# as.numeric vs chr

Tags: r

I have the following code

```
fig4 <- data.frame(chads=NA,age=NA,treatment=NA,mean=NA,lower=NA,upper=NA)
fig4$chads <- as.factor(fig4$chads)
levels(fig4$chads) <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
fig4$age <- as.factor(fig4$age)
levels(fig4$age ) <- c("u80","o80")
fig4$treatment <- as.factor(fig4$treatment)
levels(fig4$treatment) <- c("OAC","OAP")
fig4$mean <- as.numeric(fig4$mean)
fig4$lower <- as.numeric(fig4$lower)
fig4$upper <- as.numeric(fig4$upper)

> str(fig4)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ chads    : Factor w/ 7 levels "0","1","2","3",..: NA
 $ age      : Factor w/ 2 levels "u80","o80": NA
 $ treatment: Factor w/ 2 levels "OAC","OAP": NA
 $ mean     : num NA
 $ lower    : num NA
 $ upper    : num NA
```

So far so good. But then I do this:

```
vc <- as.vector(c(6,"o80","OAC",0.1,0.02,0.25), mode = "any")
fig4 <- rbind(fig4,vc)
```

which results in this:

```
> str(fig4)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ chads    : Factor w/ 7 levels "0","1","2","3",..: NA 7
 $ age      : Factor w/ 2 levels "u80","o80": NA 2
 $ treatment: Factor w/ 2 levels "OAC","OAP": NA 1
 $ mean     : chr  NA "0.1"
 $ lower    : chr  NA "0.02"
 $ upper    : chr  NA "0.25"
```

Why did the numeric vectors turn into character ones ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lists can hold objects of multiple types, so to avoid your new data being converted to character, you can do:

```
fig4[nrow(fig4) + 1, ] <- list(6,"o80","OAC",0.1,0.02,0.25)
```

Answer (score 2):

For the same reason a matrix would --- both vector and matrix can hold only *one* type.  And as you force character into the mix, you get character.

Use a data.frame to hold "columns" of different types, then subset individual columns.